Python 3.13 Juypter Lab install PC
I am using the latest python version and can not get jupyter lab installed correctly.  I always get the following errors. I know this is a common error and I have tried all the other suggestions of new tool boxes etc.  New to python but advanced SQL coder so this is frustrating.
× Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [6 lines of output]
  Cargo, the Rust package manager, is not installed or is not on PATH.
  This package requires Rust and Cargo to compile extensions. Install it through
  the system's package manager or via https://rustup.rs/

  Checking for Rust toolchain....
  [end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

Related SO post but with no answer Why does Jupyter Lab install fail without Rust?. The comments have links to some suggestions though.
